# Extrapolating the sequence of derivatives of an analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, numerical-methods, extrapolation

Suppose that $f(x)$ is an analytic complex or real function on the real domain and we only know $f(x_0)$ and the first $n$ derivatives of $f(x)$ at $x=x_0$. Is there an algorithm whose accuracy increases as $n$ gets larger that gives an approximation for the next derivative at the same point?

Comment: Another formulation of the problem: how do I determine the other Taylor coefficients of a function if I only know the first few ones? With that: one could try to construct a Padé approximant of the function from these given derivative values, and use the series expansion of that approximant to get estimates of higher-order Taylor coefficients.

Comment: Knowing the first n derivatives at a point is equivalent to knowing the first n coefficients of the Taylor expansion at that point, and the n+1st coefficient isn't constrained by the first n in any way.  You'd need more information.  More directly, f(z) and f(z)+cz^(n+1) have the same first n derivatives (at z=0), but totally unrelated n+1st derivatives.